# difference between Flat and Material design illustration

Tags: illustration, google-material-design, flat-design

What's the difference between Flat and Material design illustration? Even, Are they any different? For example, what can I call the picture below?

[image]

Comment: The picture above is considered Flat Design, there is nothing about it which uses Material Design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Material Design is about how elements interact with their surrounding. Flat design is a design style, Material Design is a visual language that uses the minimal/flat design style. Google sough out to create a system that unifies the user experience across platforms, devices, and input methods.

**Some differences**

- Material design takes a life-like approach to how animations function in digital spaces. Material as metaphor: visual cues should be grounded in reality.
- Material Design can look like a flat style but Material Design will take z-axis into consideration.
- There are several rules to Material Design that you cannot break, like Material elements cannot fold or bend. Unlike flat design, [you can show some transparency to show elevation](https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html#elevation-in-material-design).

Check out the [introduction to Material Design](https://material.io/design/introduction/#) for more information.

Comment: "all Material elements are opaque or no Material elements can fold or bend." then flat designs cannot be opaque neither.

Comment: But I can see some icons on my android phone that are folded!

Comment: @FaridS All of Google doesn't follow Material Design.

Comment: @FaridS and Icons can have folds in them, the bend rule refers to animations and how it interacts.